# Filter a tuple of types in c++17

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++17

`std::tuple a{1,3,4,5}` -> make it to numbers greater than 3

```
std::tuple b{4,5}
```

Or

```
std::tuple a{
    std::integral_constant<int,1> {},
    std::integral_constant<int,3> {},
    std::integral_constant<int,4> {},
    std::integral_constant<int,5> {} 
}
```

to

```
std::tuple a{
    std::integral_constant<int,4>{},
    std::integral_constant<int,5>{}
};
```

How to convert this at compile time? I can do this using `integer_sequence` but that is a cumbersome. Is there a simpler way in C++17 using fold expressions or `std::apply`

Also after filter, also need to get a tuple of unique entries. But my assumption is if filtering can be done, then finding unique would be trivial.

Edit so that is more clear: 
`std::tuple<int_c<1>, int_c<3>,int_c<4>,int_c<5>> to std::tuple<int_c<4>,int_c<5>` <-- If such is possible in a concise c++17 way without extra declare functions, it would do!.

Edit: 
I was fiddling around, maybe something like this would work:

with `template... C` as the list of integrals constants:

```
constexpr auto result = std::tuple_cat(std::conditional_t<(C::value > 3), std::tuple<C>, std::tuple<>>{}...);
```

Comment: result type should be known at compile type, you cannot do that according to values.

Comment: It is possible if the result is `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: but you can convert `template <std::size_t N>using int_c = std::integral_constant<int, N>; std::tuple<int_c<1>, int_c<3>,int_c<4>,int_c<5>>` to `std::tuple<int_c<4>,int_c<5>>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 would it not be possible if the values are actually wrapped types?

Comment: ` std::tuple<int_c<1>, int_c<3>,int_c<4>,int_c<5>> to std::tuple<int_c<4>,int_c<5>` <-- Yes if this is possible that should do!

Answer (score 11):

To turn out your `tuple_cat` with c++17:

```
constexpr auto result = std::apply([](auto...ts) {
    return std::tuple_cat(std::conditional_t<(decltype(ts)::value > 3),
                          std::tuple<decltype(ts)>,
                          std::tuple<>>{}...);
}, tup);
```

Comment: This gives the right direction for a concise solution, but the code here does not compile. I replaced the first `Ts...` with `auto... ts`, and the other `Ts` with `decltype(ts)`: it then worked perfectly.

Comment: what if the input is `std::tuple a{1,3,4,5}`, this approach relies on encoding the value into a type `integral_constant` which can be used as a template argument. It does not matter anyway for int, but when the tuple element is a constexpr struct, using integral_constant is verbose.

Comment: @zoujyjs: return type cannot rely on runtime value. You might use something like `template<auto... Values> using tupleValue = std::tuple<std::integral_constant<decltype(Values), Values>...>;` to reduce verbosity (so `tupleValue<1, 3, 4, 5, '*', 1ULL>`).

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to produce a trait that will output `std::tuple<T>` for desirable elements `T` and `std::tuple<>` for undesirable elements and to use [`std::tuple_cat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) to recombine those tuples into a single type. For example :

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename Pred, typename Tuple> struct filter;

template <typename t_Predicate, typename ...Ts> 
struct filter<t_Predicate, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    // If this element has to be kept, returns `std::tuple<Ts>`
    // Otherwise returns `std::tuple<>`
    template<class E>
    using t_filter_impl = std::conditional_t<
        t_Predicate<E>::value,
        std::tuple<E>, std::tuple<>>;

    // Determines the type that would be returned by `std::tuple_cat`
    //  if it were called with instances of the types reported by 
    //  t_filter_impl for each element
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<t_filter_impl<Ts>>()...));
};
```

Where `t_Predicate<T>` is any predicate type with a `bool value;` member which determines whether or not `T` is a desirable type. For example to apply this solution to the original question, first write a predicate type specialized for `std::integral_constant` :

```
// Non integral_constant are not kept
template<class T>
struct four_or_more : std::integral_constant<bool, false> {};

// integral_const types are kept if their value is >=4
template<class T, T V>
struct four_or_more<std::integral_constant<T, V>> :
    std::integral_constant<bool, V >= 4> {};
```

And here is a demonstration :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_tuple(
        std::integral_constant<int,1> {},
        std::integral_constant<int,3> {},
        std::integral_constant<int,4> {},
        std::integral_constant<int,5> {}
    );

    using b_type = filter<four_or_more, decltype(a)>::type;

    std::cout << "size : " << std::tuple_size<b_type>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::tuple_element_t<0, b_type>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::tuple_element_t<1, b_type>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you use `>= 4` to avoid issue with ending `>` of template, notice that you can use parenthesis `<bool, (V > 3)>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with new STL utilities from C++17. That would be something like that:

```
template<typename T>
auto filter(T tup) {
    return std::apply([&](auto first, auto... rest) {
        auto filtered_rest = [&]{
            if constexpr (sizeof...(rest)) {
                return filter(std::tuple{rest...});
            } else {
                return std::tuple{};
            }
        }();

        if constexpr (first > 3) {
            return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple{first}, filtered_rest);
        } else {
            return filtered_rest;
        }
    }, tup);
}
```

Of course, there is many other ways to do it. In this case I used `std::apply` and recursion. I start by an empty tuple and I add one element at a time.

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/qo63r4

Comment: won't compile, even the 2 return type of both lambda is different.

Comment: @zoujyjs Apart from the missing captures, it does compile. Check your rules again.