# How to create C++20 concept for typelist predicate?

Tags: c++, c++20

I started learning C++20's concepts. I'd like to create a `concept` for typelist's filter predicate.

Suppose, there is a typelist defined like this:

```
template <typename ...TYPE>
struct List {
};
```

And there is `Filter`, which can filter a typelist, based on a predicate. A possible definition is like this:

```
template <template <typename> typename PREDICATE, typename LIST>
struct Filter {
    using result = List<...>; // some implementation here
};
```

It means, that for each `LIST`'s `TYPE` argument, `PREDICATE<TYPE>::value` must be evaluated (it is a `bool` value), and if it's `true`, then `Filter::result` must contain `TYPE`.

Now, how can I create a `concept` for `PREDICATE`, so `Filter` will only accept it, if it contains a `value` member (for all `TYPE` specializations, which is in `LIST`)?

I mean, for this `MyPredicate`, `concept` should only allow to instantiate `Filter` with a `LIST`, which has no types besides `some_type1` and `some_type2`:

```
template <typename TYPE>
struct MyPredicate;

template <>
struct MyPredicate<some_type1> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct MyPredicate<some_type2> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

Filter<MyPredicate, List<some_type1, some_type2>>::result x; // here, x should have the type List<some_type1>
Filter<MyPredicate, List<int>>::result y; // should not compile, as MyPredicate<int> isn't defined
```

Comment: Will only one element in `List` evaluate to true?

Comment: @0x499602D2: no, it can be anything

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50971954/701092) is close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a concept to check a single instantiation:

```
template <typename T>
concept nested_value = std::same_as<decltype(T::value), bool>;
```

Which you can use in a *fold-expression*:

```
template <template <typename> class Pred, typename List>
struct Filter;

template <template <typename> class Pred, template <typename...> class L, typename... Ts>
    requires (nested_value<Pred<Ts>> && ... )
struct Filter<Pred, L<Ts...>> {
    // ...
};
```

Or you can basically do the same thing in a concept:

```
template <template <typename> class Pred, typename List>
struct all_nested_impl : std::false_type { };

template <template <typename> class Pred, template <typename...> class L, typename... Ts>
struct all_nested_impl<Pred, L<Ts...>>
    : std::bool_constant<(nested_value<Pred<Ts>> && ...)>
{ };

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename List>
concept all_nested = all_nested_impl<Pred, List>::value;

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename List>
    requires all_nested<Pred, List>
struct Filter;
```

Or if you just flip the parameters, you'd be able to write:

```
template <template <typename> class Pred, all_nested<Pred> List>
struct Filter;
```

Comment: He wants a `List<T...>` that contains all the elements in a given `List<U...>` for which `Predicate<U>::value` is true. He wants to filter out all the ones that aren't.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's not what the question is asking for: "how can I create a concept for PREDICATE, so Filter will only accept it, if it contains a value member (for all TYPE specializations, which is in LIST)?"

Comment: @0x499602D2 is right, I meant that `value` is a `bool` member, not a type (see my example), and `Filter` will put the type into result, if this `bool value` is `true`. But I think that I can modify your answer, so it behaves like I wanted to. Sorry about the confusion (I see, that by "accept", you meant a different thing than I did).

Comment: @geza Huh? If 0x4 is right, then my answer has nothing to do with the question. But then concepts have nothing to do with the question either. So what is it you actually want?

Comment: Hmm. Why concepts have nothing to do with my question? I'd like to have concepts, so I'll get better error messages (they are not mandatory for the filtering problem). Your solution solves the problem, it's just you used `value` as a type, and not as a `bool` value. I easily modified your solution, and it does what I want.

Comment: @geza Yeah I fixed the type/value thing.